# Printing asterisk ("*") in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

```
a=5
echo "*/$aMin * * * * bash /etc/init.d/ckDskCheck.sh"
```

When I try to run the following code, it displays properly

```
*/5 * * * * bash /etc/init.d/ckDskCheck.sh
```

But when I try to assign the result using the following code to the variable and print it out, it displays as this:

```
a=5
cronSen=`echo "*/$a * * * * bash /etc/init.d/ckDskCheck.sh"`
echo $cronSen
```

Result:

[image]

So I try to escape the asterisk by

```
cronSen=`echo "\*/$a \* \* \* \* bash /etc/init.d/ckDskCheck.sh"`
```

But it still doesn't work. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Quote `$cronSen` when you echo it.

Comment: Quote all variables that don't have a specific reason to be unquoted.

Comment: @EtanReisner,@n.m Thanks for the reply, it works now! But just curious to know when should I put/not put the quotes? Is there any norms to follow?

Comment: Are you sure you use bash? My bash not show like you desribed. Anyway you need do  echo "$varname" if you want it be not substituted *.

Comment: @user2499325 As tripleee indicates in his answer. Quote everything you use as part of a command that you run unless you know you want the shell to perform word splitting and other expansions on it.

Comment: Why would you run an `init.d` script from Cron, though?  Either it's in the wrong location or else you are doing something moderately funky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Useless Use of Echo in Backticks
2. Always quote what you `echo`

So the fixed code is

```
a=5
cronSen="*/$a * * * * bash /etc/init.d/ckDskCheck.sh"
echo "$cronSen"
```

It appears you may also have a Useless Use of Variable, but perhaps `cronSen` is useful in a larger context.

In short, quote everything where you do not require the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion.

Token splitting;

```
 words="foo bar baz"
 for word in $words; do
      :
```

(This loops three times. Quoting `$words` would only loop once over the literal token `foo bar baz`.)

Wildcard expansion:

```
pattern='file*.txt'
ls $pattern
```

(Quoting `$pattern` would attempt to list a single file whose name is literally `file*.txt`.)

In more concrete terms, anything containing a filename should usually be quoted.

A variable containing a list of tokens to loop over or a wildcard to expand is less frequently seen, so we sometimes abbreviate to "quote everything unless you know precisely what you are doing".

Comment: Copied choice parts of this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable/27701642#27701642

Answer (score 5):

You must use double quote when echo your variable:

```
echo "$cronSen"
```

If you don't use double quote, `bash` will see `*` and perform [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion). `*` expands to all files in your current directory.