# Mail sending with shell Scipt is not working

Tags: shell, email, sh

I need to send a mail regarding deployment of an application using shell script.
For this I have just created a shell script and tested with

```
#!/bin/bash

TO_ADDRESS="to.person@domain.com"
FROM_ADDRESS="from.me@domain.com"
SUBJECT="Test mail"
BODY="hai friend, this mail is automated from shell script for Release automation."

echo ${BODY}| mail -s ${SUBJECT} ${TO_ADDRESS} -- -r ${FROM_ADDRESS}
```

But while running this script, it is printing like:

```
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/jaykay
```

And a file named `jaykay` is created in `/var/spool/mail/`

- Why this is happening?
- How can I send a mail using shell script?

And the output file looks like

```
From jaykay Wed Aug 20 04:08:53 2014
Return-Path: <jaykay>
Received: (from jaykay@localhost)
    by e7021.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id s7K98rdu004168;
    Wed, 20 Aug 2014 04:08:53 -0500
From: Jini K Johny <jaykay>
Message-Id: <201408200908.s7K98rdu004168@e7021.com>
Date: Wed, 20 Aug 2014 04:08:53 -0500
To: to.person@domain.com, -r, --, from.me@domain.com
Subject: Test mail
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

hai friend, this mail is automated from shell script for Release automation.
```

Comment: you are missing a `}` in your last line on `${FROM_ADDRESS`.

Comment: did you setup a mail server yet? For instance `OpenSmtpd` https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~bn0/mail_tutorial.html

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez it was a typo, updated now. thanks for the review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you **must** use proper quoting.  This is basically a duplicate of a question which gets asked here every day.

Without quotes, the second token in `$SUBJECT` is interpreted as the address to send to.

- An email is submitted for delivery to `mail` (the second word in `"Test mail"`).
- The address is undeliverable, so you get a bounce message.
- The bounce message is delivered to your inbox.
- Your shell notifies you that your inbox has a new message.

Additionally, it seems that your version of `mail` does not understand the `--` option, so it gets taken as just one more address to send to.  (You would get a bounce message from that, I suppose.)  Because the `-r` option is also interpreted as just another address to send to, you get one copy (like a `Bcc:`) of the outgoing message in the mailbox you tried to specify in the `$FROM_ADDRESS`.

The fix, of course, is easy:

```
#!/bin/bash

TO_ADDRESS="to.person@domain.com"
FROM_ADDRESS="from.me@domain.com"
SUBJECT="Test mail"
BODY="hai friend, this mail is automated from shell script for Release automation."

echo "${BODY}" | mail -s "${SUBJECT}" "${TO_ADDRESS}"  # -- -r "${FROM_ADDRESS}"
```

(The curlies aren't really necessary here, but I kept them since you had them in your code.)

E.g. [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277434/874188) has guidance for when and how exactly you need to quote.

The `mail` program is really a rather thin wrapper; you could do something like this instead;

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t -f "$FROM_ADDRESS" <<____HERE
From: My Name <$FROM_ADDRESS>
To: Your Name <$TO_ADDRESS>
Subject: $SUBJECT

$BODY
____HERE
```

... where the path to `/usr/lib/sendmail` is likely to be something else on many systems.

(For bonus k00lness points, add `X-Mailer: Look, I can put anything I like here!`)

I'm guessing here that you meant `sendmail -f "$FROM_ADDRESS"` which sets the envelope sender address (not `-r` which I cannot find documented anywhere).

Comment: No change in the output. :(

Comment: What's in `/var/spool/mail/jaykay`?  I'm guessing you are getting a bounce message or automatic response for some other reason, and that the bounce message tells you why.

Comment: Guessing the `-r` option is erroneous, I can't find any documentation for it.  Did you mean `-f`?

Comment: am in new with this shell script. :(

Comment: But from and to are different, and the mail is not delivering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59634/discussion-between-tripleee-and-jaykay).