# E-Mail's body format after procmail processing

Tags: linux, procmail

I have the following scenerio:

SMTP server on the GNU/Linux machine is accepting mails. Accepted mail is being sent to procmail for further processing. Here's my *.procmailrc*:

```
VERBOSE=yes
LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log
SUBJECT=`formail -xSubject: | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/^ //' | /usr/bin/perl -MEncode -ne 'print encode ("utf8",decode ("MIME-Header",$_ )) '`
FROM=`formail -rt -xTo:`
DATE=`formail -xDate:`
BODY=`formail -I ""`
:0fbW
* ^From.*some_special_name@special_server.com
| echo "FROM:$FROM" > $HOME/res.txt; \
  echo "DATE:$DATE" >> $HOME/res.txt; \
  echo "SUB:$SUBJECT" >> $HOME/res.txt; \
  echo "BODY:" >> $HOME/res.txt; \
  echo $BODY >> $HOME/res.txt; process.py
```

This little script first creates a local file *$HOME/res.txt* and then launches another script called *process.py*. Now, the *$HOME/res.txt* is populated with the following entries:

```
FROM:some_special_name@special_server.com
DATE:Mon, 06 Oct 2014 13:14:32 +0200
SUB:Some subject
BODY:
This is a multi-part message in MIME format. --------------030006020609010705060803 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Hello, Some kind of long tekst where I cannot see the line feed chars nor any other control chars...
```

The body contains the raw string without the original format of the body. What I mean by this is that \n or \t characters are filtered out. The *process.py* script demands the body part of the message to maintain the original format of the email message.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could use `formail -zxSubject:` to make the `sed` part unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in shell scripts, you need to properly duoble-quote variables unless you specifically require the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion on the value.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25277434/874188) for a detailed explanation.

```
  echo "$BODY" >>$HOME/res.txt; \
```

Additionally, I don't understand why you mix multiple actions like that.  Between the lines, I guess you mean that `process.py` reads `res.txt` instead of its standard input; if it were reading standard input, it would receive the correct, unmangled message.

Without context, I'll go out on a limb and speculate that the `f` flag is also wrong.  Unless `process.py` prints a new message on standard output which should replace the incoming message for the remainder of your Procmail recipe file, you should simply take it out.

There is also a race condition here: if multiple messages arrive at roughly the same time (where "same time" can be a rather wide window if your system is under heavy load), they will overwrite `res.txt` and trample over each others' results in unpredicable ways.  The customary solution to that is to use a local lock file; but the vastly superior solution is to remove the need for a temporary file, and change `process.py` so that it reads standard input instead.

Since you are using Python anyway, I would do all the header parsing in Python, with the possible exception of `formail -rtzxTo:`, which is rather complex to reimplement; this would simplify your Procmail recipe significantly, and probably improve `process.py` (or the wrapper you create, if you cannot modify it).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Frankly speaking I used to use the "" trick quite often while scripting, but this time my memory apparently failed me. By the way, I deleted the f flag, and all still works fine!

Comment: Er, it's not a "trick", it's a fundamental feature of the shell.

Comment: You're right! In answer to your query: yes, process.py reads res.txt for futher analysis. Good guess ;-) Quite likely I will need to elaborate it a bit more to send it to a remote server where the final version of process.py will take care of that file. Now it's in an early stage of development.