# Concatenating asterisks in bash

Tags: bash, special-characters, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate asterisks (`*`) to a string variable. However, I keep getting the files in the current directory instead. I have tried

```
row+='*'
row+=$row     #where row is *
row='*'"$row"
row="\*$row"
row="${row}*"
```

etc.

```
row='*'."$row"  #produces *.*.*.
```

I thought `\` would escape the `*`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I kept searching for concatenating * and never for just printing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes around the variable before you "print".

For example:

```
cronSen="*/$a * * * * bash /etc/init.d/ckDskCheck.sh"
echo "$cronSen"
```

This could work. I got the idea from here: [Printing asterisk (*) in bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277037/printing-asterisk-in-bash-shell)

Comment: Fixed. I added also where I got the solution. Trying out.